# The isomorphism class of the 1-representation of a complete quiver

Tags: co.combinatorics, quivers

Let $Q$ be a [quiver](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Embrion/notes_quivers_rev.pdf) with vertex set $Q_0$ and the arrows $Q_1$. A quiver self $Q$ is said to be complete if it has no loops and for every arrow in $Q_1$ the opposite arrow is also in $Q_1$.

A representation $(V_i,f_i)_{i \in Q_1}$ is said to be a $1$-representation if $V_i = V_j$ for each $i$ and $f_i$ is the identity linear transformation.

My questions:

1. How to find the isomorphism class of the $1$-representation of a quiver Q?
2. How to find whether a representation of $Q$ belongs to this class?
3. is there any combinatorial description of elements of this class?
4. is this class of particular importance in the theory of finite quivers?

Kindly share your thought and thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: "*A representation $(V_i, f_i)_{i \in Q_1}$ …*" Shouldn't the $V_i$ and $f_i$ be indexed separately, by $Q_0$ and $Q_1$ respectively?

Comment: Since your $1$-representation consists only of identity maps, it'll be uniquely determined by the dimension vector. So since the dimension at the vertices are all the same, they're indexed by $\mathbf{N}$?